# SQL Server SELECT To Return String Including Single Quotes

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

I need to get a formatted string with data from a SELECT statement.  The problem is that I need it to return with single quotes.  Here's an example.

I have a table that contains 2 columns TrainingSwipeID (int) and ExtendedDate (datetime).  For an example I have a row in the table that contains

TrainingSwipeID = 123

TrainingEnd = 04/23/2019 09:00:00

I need to create a SELECT statement that will return the formatted string such as
{'TrainingSwipeID':123,'TrainingEnd ':04/23/2019 09:00:00}

I've researched and found that you can double single quote to get around this issue.  I've tried the following with no luck and I get the following error "Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '{'TrainingSwipeID':' to data type int."

```
SELECT '{''TrainingSwipeID'':' + TrainingSwipeID + '''TrainingEnd'':' + TrainingEnd + '}' 
AS MyFormattedString 
FROM TrainingSwipe
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Replace TrainingSwipeID with `convert(varchar(x), TrainingSwipeID)` where x is a good length to cover your IDs. Presumably you'd also need to format the date in a specific way as well. See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#date-and-time-styles) for some styles.

Comment: use KISS principle. `select concat('{''TrainingSwipeID'':' , TrainingSwipeID, ',''TrainingEnd'':', TrainingEnd, '}')`

Comment: Thanks @AlexKudryashev.  This works perfectly and is simple as you said.  :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally used the simplest answer from @AlexKudryashev but Luis' answer worked as well.

```
SELECT CONCAT('{''TrainingSwipeID'':' , TrainingSwipeID, ',''TrainingEnd'':', TrainingEnd, '}')
```

Answer (score 2):

The numeric and date/time data types have a higher precedence than the string data types. That's why you need to convert the numeric types into strings and prevent undesired implicit conversions.

```
SELECT '{''TrainingSwipeID'':' + CAST(TrainingSwipeID AS varchar(15)) 
      + '''TrainingEnd'':' + CONVERT( varchar(20), TrainingEnd , 101) + ' ' 
      + CONVERT( varchar(20), TrainingEnd , 8) + '}' 
AS MyFormattedString 
FROM TrainingSwipe
```

Comment: Thanks Luis, I had to remove the second SELECT but this works as well.  :)

Comment: Silly me, that was a copy-paste issue. It's corrected now.